# GenyMotion 4.3 Image fails to launch application

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have updated to Genymotion 2.0 and downloaded/deployed the new 4.3 images (Galaxy Nexus and 10.1 Tablet) upon installing the appropriate GApps package get a devastating error upon launching a development app with the following stack  trace making the device restart.

```
I/Process ( 3117): Sending signal. PID: 3117 SIG: 9
E/AndroidRuntime( 3117): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: android.server.ServerThread
E/AndroidRuntime( 3117): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider doesn't exisit: null
E/AndroidRuntime( 3117):    at com.android.server.LocationManagerService.requestLocationUpdatesLocked(LocationManagerService.java:1323)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3117):    at com.android.server.LocationManagerService.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManagerService.java:1302)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3117):    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:836)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3117):    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:461)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3117):    at com.android.location.fused.FusionEngine.enableProvider(FusionEngine.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3117):    at com.android.location.fused.FusionEngine.updateRequirements(FusionEngine.java:191)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3117):    at com.android.location.fused.FusionEngine.setRequest(FusionEngine.java:114)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3117):    at com.android.location.fused.FusedLocationProvider$2.handleMessage(FusedLocationProvider.java:98)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3117):    at androi
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running an image with Google Apps API installed?

Comment: I am. I sideloaded the gapps 20130813 package. Google Play and all other related google apps are installed and working correctly.

Comment: Maybe it's not related, but who knows...try turning on Genymotion's GPS (and also make sure all of the location services are turned on in the settings)

Comment: Henrique, good suggestion. Though upon trying that same thing happened.

Comment: Hello, are you using Google Maps V2 or V1??  Did you add these permissions to your manifest:
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.my.packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.my.packagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For what I know the last update to `Genymotion` removed the support for `google apps` and `google-play-service` from it's images because of some disagreement with Google, you can read more about it here:

https://plus.google.com/+GenymotionEmulator/posts/jNF8Kwu5p1c

So from now on, you can't run `Google Maps API V2` applications and use other features of the `google-play-service` like the `LocationManager` you are trying to use.

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in the comments you could install the GApps package manually using the following guide:

http://blog.zeezonline.com/2013/11/install-google-play-on-genymotion-2-0/

Comment: Except for the fact that you can sideload the GApps package onto your GenyMotion devices. thus making them "useful" or at least "less-useless" again.

Comment: this you could do using the standard emulator as well, so I don't give them credit for that, the whole point of Genymotion for most developers was that it come build in with google-play-services support.

Comment: Yes, though from my experience with GenyMotion I like that they already have images setup. And 2) I have always had faster responses from GenyMotion than the "standard emulator".

Comment: It's true but if you install the Intel HAXM driver the experience is almost the same.

Comment: Then maybe there is something else different on my Mac, since I have installed and used the Intel HAXM drivers ... still the native emulator in the sdk is pretty slow (faster than before, but still slow) Especially in comparison to speeds I get in Genymotion.

Comment: do you maybe have a guide for side-loading the GApps to Genymotion? what apk files do you use?

Comment: Never mind, found this: http://blog.zeezonline.com/2013/11/install-google-play-on-genymotion-2-0/

Comment: Yes that is it. Though make sure you use the correct version of the GApps package for the appropriate API version # used.

Comment: I have the correct package. I also know this is only on 4.3 images for GenyMotion as using the appropriate GApps package and 4.2.2 image my application works flawlessly with the GenyMotion emulated device.

Comment: ~"you can't run Google Maps API V2".  I can still run Google Maps V2 apps in Genymotion just fine...

Comment: If you left the image that was provided for you before, the new update removed those images from Genymotion so new installs wont have it.