# google maps cant appear in my application android

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I tried to insert a google map at my android application! but anytime i run my application i got an empty white card!! Can you please help me?
here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ca.sfu.cmpt276.bfraser"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission 
        android:name="ca.sfu.cmpt276.bfraser.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="ca.sfu.cmpt276.bfraser.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data 
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>


        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyAKSGZf3QfsI_TDjFymsq_4sJy3DotPqjE"/>



        <activity
            android:name="ca.sfu.cmpt276.bfraser.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my xml code  is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ca.sfu.cmpt276.bfraser.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
          android:layout_below="@+id/header"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I follow the tutorial [[https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2][1]](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2%5d%5b1%5d)

and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awX5T-EwLPc but i get always the same problem : the google maps cant appear in in the emulator that i use: i know that the google maps api v2 cant work in emulator i install Genymotion that is solution in this forum but the same problem. My activity code is :

```
package ca.sfu.cmpt276.bfraser;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    //private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //map=((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


    }



}
```

thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because Genymotion does not support the google library play yet. Please follow this tutorial for installing the library to your Genymotion

[GenyMotion 4.3 Image fails to launch application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20009968/genymotion-4-3-image-fails-to-launch-application)